# JaCoCo Gradle - Exclude classes & override Includes

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, jacoco, jacoco-plugin

I am attempting to refine my code coverage in my project, and want to exclude any `View` classes (as they are not tested/testable) but include any `ViewModel` classes... but I can't seem to get the wildcard filters to cooperate, it's all or nothing!

```
def excludedPatterns = [
        //... other stuff

        '**/*Fragment*.*',
        '**/*Activity*.*',
        '**/*Adapter*.*',

        '**/*View*.*', // <-- this line is excluding classes ending w/ ViewModel

        '**/*ViewState*.*',
        '**/*ViewHolder*.*',
]

task codeCoverageReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'testDebugUnitTest') {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."

    reports {
        html.enabled true
    }

    def debugTree = fileTree(
            dir: "$project.buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug",
            excludes: excludedPatterns
    )
    classDirectories.from = files([debugTree])

    def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"
    sourceDirectories.from = files([mainSrc])

    executionData.from = fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: [
            'jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec',
            'outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec'
    ])
}
```

I've tried several variations of `**/*View*.*'`, including `**/*View.*'` and others... 
Is there something that I am overlooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`filter` on `fileTree`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html#filter-groovy.lang.Closure-).

For example for

`src/main/java/View.java`

```
class View {}
```

`src/main/java/ViewModel.java`

```
class ViewModel {}
```

`src/main/java/Example.java`

```
class Example {}
```

`src/test/java/ExampleTest.java`

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleTest {
    @Test
    public final void test() {
    }
}
```

and `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    classDirectories.setFrom(
        fileTree(dir: "build/classes/java/main")
            .filter({file -> !file.name.contains('View') || file.name.contains('ViewModel')})
    )
}
```

Execution of

```
gradle clean test jacocoTestReport
```

using Gradle 6.2.1 will generate the following report in directory `build/reports/jacoco/test/html/` that doesn't contain `View`, but contains `ViewModel` and `Example`:

[image: report]

Comment: thx! going to test this out, will report back + accept answer if it works...

Comment: Is this supposed to go in the root Gradle or the app/ one? 
Also, I am currently stuck on Gradle 5.X, is this a 6.X exclusive feature ?

Comment: nv, figured this out. using the property syntax I was able to simply go



`classDirectories.from = files([debugTree]).filter({file -> file.name.contains('ViewModel')})`